# I need help building a todo App in vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

i have a problem where i want to code a todo list with vue js.

- In my todo list i can add a task and click a button to add it to the list.
- The new Task appears at "All Tasks" and Not finished"
- I have the buttons "not done! and done! for All Tasks and Not finished Tasks
- If the Task is done, the Task should disappear from "All Tasks" and appear in "finished"
- If the Task is is not finished it should stay in "note finished" with only one button for "done"!

Here is what i have so far. I dont know what to do to get this toDo list to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="lib/js/vue.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="todoapp">
      <h1>TO-DO</h1>
      <p>
        <label for="newtask">Add new Task</label>
        <input id="newtask" type="text" v-model="newtasks" />
        <button class="hinzu" v-on:click="newtask">Add</button>
      </p>

      <h1>All Tasks</h1>

      <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks">
          {{aufgabe}}<br /><button class="Task not done!">not done!</button
          ><button class="Task done!">done!</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <h2>Not finished</h2>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks">
          {{aufgabe}}<br /><button class="Task not done!">not done</button
          ><button class="Task done!" v-on:click="done">done!</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <h2>finished</h2>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = new Vue({
        el: "#todoapp",
        data() {
          return {
            tasks: [],
          };
        },
        methods: {
          newtask() {
            this.tasks.push(this.newtasks);
          },

          done() {
            this.tasks.pop(this.newtasks);
          },
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have pasted the same code block twice. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Im sorry, i didn't want do post it twice. My mistake! I don't know how i can get the finished tasks to go to "finished" and to disapear from "All tasks" and "not finished" Im totally new to vue.js and js in general. Its really hard for me to understand all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found following errors:

```
   <input id="newtask" type="text" v-model="newtasks" />
```

The `newtasks` data property is not defined. Should be in the `data()`.

You use the `task` as variable in the iterator but try to show `{{aufgabe}}` which is not defined.

```
<li v-for="task in tasks">
    {{aufgabe}}<br /><button class="Task not done!">not done</button>
    <button class="Task done!" v-on:click="done">done!</button>
</li>
```

Here is playground with fixed code.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#todoapp",
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      newtasks: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    newtask() {
      this.tasks.push(this.newtasks);
    },

    done() {
      this.tasks.pop(this.newtasks);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
 <div id="todoapp">
  <h1>TO-DO</h1>
  <p>
    <label for="newtask">Add new Task</label>
    <input id="newtask" type="text" v-model="newtasks" />
    <button class="hinzu" v-on:click="newtask">Add</button>
  </p>

  <h1>All Tasks</h1>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks">
      {{task}}<br /><button class="Task not done!">not done!</button
      ><button class="Task done!">done!</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h2>Not finished</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks">
      {{task}}<br /><button class="Task not done!">not done</button
      ><button class="Task done!" v-on:click="done">done!</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h2>finished</h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i put task that are finished to the "finished" headline?

Comment: ok, pls close this thread. It does not work. I don't want to work on this anymore. Bye